# Bootstrap 4 carousel no funciona

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4

Estoy armando un carousel múltiple con bootstrap 4. Se me presentó el problema que no gira: se queda con las imágenes estáticas, pero en [la página de donde saqué el ejemplo](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/dl6ez) sí funciona y cuando lo subo a mi código y lo hago correr no funciona. Revisé varias veces pero no encuentro la falla.

Subo el código:

```js
$('#carouselExample').on('slide.bs.carousel', function(e) {

  var $e = $(e.relatedTarget);
  var idx = $e.index();
  var itemsPerSlide = 4;
  var totalItems = $('.carousel-item').length;

  if (idx >= totalItems - (itemsPerSlide - 1)) {
    var it = itemsPerSlide - (totalItems - idx);
    for (var i = 0; i < it; i++) {
      // append slides to end
      if (e.direction == "left") {
        $('.carousel-item').eq(i).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
      } else {
        $('.carousel-item').eq(0).appendTo('.carousel-inner');
      }
    }
  }
});


$('#carouselExample').carousel({
  interval: 2000
});


$(document).ready(function() {
  /* show lightbox when clicking a thumbnail */
  $('a.thumb').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var content = $('.modal-body');
    content.empty();
    var title = $(this).attr("title");
    $('.modal-title').html(title);
    content.html($(this).html());
    $(".modal-profile").modal({
      show: true
    });
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <!-- This file has been downloaded from Bootsnipp.com. Enjoy! -->
  <title>bootstrap 4 multiple carousel - Bootsnipp.com</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css">
    @media (min-width: 768px) {
      /* show 3 items */
      .carousel-inner .active,
      .carousel-inner .active+.carousel-item,
      .carousel-inner .active+.carousel-item+.carousel-item,
      .carousel-inner .active+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
        display: block;
      }
      .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left),
      .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)+.carousel-item,
      .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)+.carousel-item+.carousel-item,
      .carousel-inner .carousel-item.active:not(.carousel-item-right):not(.carousel-item-left)+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
        transition: none;
      }
      .carousel-inner .carousel-item-next,
      .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
      }
      .carousel-inner .active.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: -25%;
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
      }
      /* left or forward direction */
      .active.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left,
      .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item,
      .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item+.carousel-item,
      .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item,
      .carousel-item-next.carousel-item-left+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(-100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
      }
      /* farthest right hidden item must be abso position for animations */
      .carousel-inner .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        z-index: -1;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
      }
      /* right or prev direction */
      .active.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right,
      .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item,
      .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item+.carousel-item,
      .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item,
      .carousel-item-prev.carousel-item-right+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item+.carousel-item {
        position: relative;
        transform: translate3d(100%, 0, 0);
        visibility: visible;
        display: block;
        visibility: visible;
      }
    }
    /* Bootstrap Lightbox using Modal */
    
    #profile-grid {
      overflow: auto;
      white-space: normal;
    }
    
    #profile-grid .profile {
      padding-bottom: 40px;
    }
    
    #profile-grid .panel {
      padding: 0
    }
    
    #profile-grid .panel-body {
      padding: 15px
    }
    
    #profile-grid .profile-name {
      font-weight: bold;
    }
    
    #profile-grid .thumbnail {
      margin-bottom: 6px;
    }
    
    #profile-grid .panel-thumbnail {
      overflow: hidden;
    }
    
    #profile-grid .img-rounded {
      border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>



  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div id="carouselExample" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="9000">
      <div class="carousel-inner row w-100 mx-auto" role="listbox">
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-3  active">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-thumbnail">
              <a href="#" title="image 1" class="thumb">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=1" alt="slide 1">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-thumbnail">
              <a href="#" title="image 3" class="thumb">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=2" alt="slide 2">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-thumbnail">
              <a href="#" title="image 4" class="thumb">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=3" alt="slide 3">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-thumbnail">
              <a href="#" title="image 5" class="thumb">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=4" alt="slide 4">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-thumbnail">
              <a href="#" title="image 6" class="thumb">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=5" alt="slide 5">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-thumbnail">
              <a href="#" title="image 7" class="thumb">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=6" alt="slide 6">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-3 ">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-thumbnail">
              <a href="#" title="image 8" class="thumb">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=7" alt="slide 7">
              </a>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="carousel-item col-md-3  ">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-thumbnail">
              <a href="#" title="image 2" class="thumb">
                <img class="img-fluid mx-auto d-block" src="//via.placeholder.com/600x400?text=8" alt="slide 8">
              </a>
            </div>

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next text-faded" href="#carouselExample" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: ¿donde esta el elemento con el id `carouselExample` en tu html?

Comment: Moviendo el código a snippet, sí funciona. ¿O qué problema estás teniendo?

Comment: *Se me presentó el problema que no gira: se queda con las imágenes estáticas* -> me hace entender que tus imágenes no se mueven (de izquierda a derecha o derecha a izquierda), de la cual en el snippet veo que sí está funcionando =/

Comment: Efectivamente ya lo solucione lo que paso fue un error de librerias y de version  en el bootstrap... muchas gracias